# Retain the values from one column if there is no match in the Join in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables, 
Table 1

```
id   value
1.   hello | world
1.   hello | world
2.   hello
3.   world
4.   my | universe
5.   world
```

Matching table - Table 2

```
id  value 
1.  hello
2.  hello
4.  universe
```

Expected output 
after doing a join and retaining old values if there is no match found

```
id new_value
1. hello
2. hello
3. world
4. universe
5. world
```

How can I achieve this in pandas, I am a beginner and I can do joins. but incase where there is no match how can I retain the values from the old column.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data frames are df1 and df2 respectively:

```
mapper = dict(df2.set_index('id')['value'])
df1['value'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['value'] if row['id'] not in mapper else mapper[row['id']], axis=1)

df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

another possibility is left join with fillna from other column:

```
df_result = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on='id', how='left', suffixes=(1,2)).drop_duplicates()
df_result['value2'].fillna(df_result['value1'], inplace=True)
```

df1 and df2 are the original tables, df_result['value2'] is what you are looking for.